# How to organize my pages by genre or category? Should I be using a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, organization

I am very new to the concept of mySQL DBs and am not sure if this is what I require to organize my website content. I am putting together a site that has a database of movies and I want to be able to have the movies divided by genre, categories, year, etc...  Some of these movies have multiple genres and categories, and I don't know how to go about organizing the content and tags.

An example of what I am looking for could be something like this:
http://www.thelonelyisland.com/videos

I really want to know if I am supposed to be using a mySQL database or whether or not there is another way to filter content.  I apologize for the naivety of the question but I have looked everywhere and have no idea what I am doing!!

Comment: Yes, you do want to be using a database of some sort, unless you don't plan on ever editing any of the movie-related content.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the fast response.  I will keep looking into it.

Comment: @Dan if you like my answer would you be so kind to accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a database would most certainly be the best thing to. This a basic layout:

Start with a movie table:
ID_movie, name, year, etc.

Genre table:
ID_genre, name.

Category table:
ID_category, name.

Movies have a many - to - many relationship with genre / category. So you will need a bridge  table between movies and genre / category. In this table you will have the combinations between movies and genre / category.

movies_genre table:
ID_movies, ID_genre

movies_category table:
ID_movies, ID_category

This is a SQL query to create the table structure and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE movie(
  id_movie INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  release_date DATETIME
  );

CREATE TABLE genre(
  id_genre INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
  );

CREATE TABLE category(
  id_category INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
  );

CREATE TABLE movie_genre (
  ID_movie_genre INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ID_movie INT,
  ID_genre INT,
  UNIQUE (ID_movie,ID_genre),
  INDEX (ID_movie,ID_genre)
  );


CREATE TABLE movie_category (
  ID_movie INT,
  ID_category INT
  );

INSERT INTO movie (name, release_date) VALUES 
('Transformers 3 Dark of the moon','2012-01-01'), 
('Harry potter and the deathly hallows 2','2011-01-01'), 
('Pirates of the caribbean. On stranger tides', '2012-01-01');

INSERT INTO genre (name) VALUES ('Action'), ('Fantasy'), ('Comedy');

INSERT INTO movie_genre(id_movie, id_genre) VALUES (1,1), (2,1),(2,2),(3,2),(3,1);
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea4d9/1)

In response to the remarks below. You could change release_date into year if you only want to have years. One way would be to turn them in to strings value (Year VARCHAR(4) instead of release_date DATETIME). Furthermore, I have include unique and index to the bridge table. Index will speed up your query time.

Below you will find a example query that will retrieve the name and genre from movie number 2. 
SELECT m.name AS Movie, g.name AS Genre FROM (movie AS m
left JOIN movie_genre AS mg
ON mg.id_movie = m.id_movie)
JOIN genre AS g
ON g.id_genre = mg.ID_genre
WHERE m.id_movie = 2;

Comment: Although I generally agree with your database design, I have a few remarks; 1. The movie_category should have a `PRIMARY KEY (ID_movie, ID_category)` or, to make it easier for the inexperienced user, add a 'id' auto number field as PK, and a `UNIQUE (ID_movie, ID_category)`. Although technically not perfect, this will allow him to simply delete a row by selecting its id.

Comment: A second note: You've used a 'date time' field to store the 'year' of the movie. As you're only storing the year, I wouldn't use a date time, as the field implies your only storing the year. I would change it to a simple 'int' field

Comment: @thaJeztah agree with your comment. I was thinking of including a primary or setting a composite key with unique. I decide against it because I might confuse the OP. I will edit my post.

Comment: @thaJeztah No but OP might decide to use an more precise date. Let say he would be interested in the movies released around X-mas. Then it would better if he has a datetime column.

Comment: And my last note is more of a personal opinion. I'd get rid of the _tablename suffixes for the ID's, just use 'id'. This way you can 'normalize' the names in all tables. In order to prevent conflicts/ambiguous column names in your queries it's preferable to always use the table name as a prefix anyway (e.g. `SELECT genre.id, genre.name FROM genres` and not `SELECT id, name FROM genre`

Comment: @Mr.Radical I *do* understand that the OP might decide to use a more precise date, in which case he should pick another name (release_date) . Using 'year' for a name and 'date time' as data-type is confusing and should really be discouraged as it *will* lead to bugs if another developer needs to continue the project

Comment: @thaJeztah with regard to the table suffixes I find it very easy combine the ID with the table. Just my way of easily referencing which ID I'm using.

Comment: @Mr.Radical of course, it's a matter of opinion, but by using the table-name as a prefix at all times, you won't need the suffix and you won't run into trouble if you need to join another table with duplicate column names. e.g. `SELECT movie.name, director.name FROM movies LEFT JOIN director ON director.movie_id = movie.id;` In this situation 'name' would be ambiguous, but because I'm using table name as a prefix at all times it doesn't lead to problems. I only use prefixes for foreign-keys (see 'director.movie_id') for which I use 'tablename_columname' as a convention

Comment: @thaJeztah I understand your remarks I include the table suffix for the exact same reason (foreign keys). B.T.W. I have edited my answer to include your remarks.

Comment: @Mr.Radical last edit; you forgot to add the UNIQUE constraint on the join-tables (bridge tables)

Comment: @thaJeztah I have included an index to both foreign keys as well.